# Fetching and using python nested list into JS using django

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have a page which displays some data. The data it displays needs to be in JS Array format (representing the python nested list).

In order to do this, I use a JS function that fetches the data from a django view:

`js function:`

```
var getDataFromFiles1 = function(theUrl) {
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
};
```

`views.py:`

```
a = MyModel.objects.get(c=b, x=y)
json_object = json.dumps(a.data)
return HttpResponse(json_object, content_type="application/javascript")
```

However, the data that comes back is `typeof` string, and I thought that I could just use `JSON.parse()` to pull into a JS Array, however this does not work:

```
var data = getDataFromFiles1(url);
console.log(data + " : " + typeof data)
data = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(data + " : " + typeof data)
```

and the logging included above gives:

`"[[\"example\", \"example\", \"example\", \"example\", \"not set\"], [\"example\", \"example\", \"example\", \"example\", \"not set\"]]" : string`

and

`[["example", "example", "example", "example", "not set"], ["example", "example", "example", "example", "not set"]] : string`

Am I missing something obvious? How do I create a JS Array object with this data (with the flexibility of not dropping the data in with template tags on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your model, but I would guess `a.data` is already JSON - so you're double-encoding it.

Drop the `json.dumps` and just return `HttpResponse(a.data, content_type="application/javascript")`.

Comment: this has an advantage over my answer and should be the accepted one: it does not waste a full `json.dumps`-->`JSON.parse` cycle!

Answer (score 1):

Try to `JSON.parse(...)` it again. Maybe the Python side is already JSON-encoding it due to `content_type="application/javascript"`.

Comment: take a look at Daniel Roseman's answer too, I think that works better!